# use isdigit with first element in for loop

Tags: c

i have code and when i read from file i want to check if first elements of the word is number if yes stop the program and this is part of my code for example `sum = x * 3 / 5`
this is ok because the sum doesn’t contain number but  `2sum` here should the program stop

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 int charClass;
 char lexeme [100]; 
 char nextChar; 
 int lexLen;
 int token; 
 int nextToken; 
FILE *in_fp, *fopen();
void addChar(); 
void getChar();
void getNonBlank(); 
int lex();

#define LETTER 0 
#define DIGIT 1 
#define UNKNOWN 99
#define INT_LIT 10
#define IDENT 11 
#define ASSIGN_OP 20 
#define ADD_OP 21 
#define SUB_OP 22 
#define MULT_OP 23
 #define DIV_OP 24 
 #define LEFT_PAREN 25 
 #define RIGHT_PAREN 26
 #define EQUAL_OP 27
 #define greater_than_OP 28
  #define key_Word_OP 29
  int main() {
  if ((in_fp = fopen("/Users/Desktop/ff.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
 printf("ERROR - cannot open front.in \n"); 
else {
getChar();
```

my problem here in for loop it check all elements not just first elements
i do not know why for example  `sum = x * 3 / 5` the program it is stop after 3 it should complete

```
do { 
 for( size_t i=0; lexeme[i]; i++ ){
        if(isdigit(lexeme[0]) )  {
    printf("erreo ");

   exit(0);
        } else{
            }
      }
      lex(); 



      } while (nextToken != EOF ); 
      }
  }
```

Comment: You are not showing the critical part: `lex()`

Comment: github.com/huichen-cs/sebesta/blob/master/parser/front.c this is all my code i do but some  little change

Comment: Post it here, is not too long

Comment: i can not actually this first time for me to use it is give me error you can find here in Github  https://github.com/huichen-cs/sebesta/blob/master/parser/front.c